# How to accept different xml formats in node express api?

Tags: arrays, node.js, xml, api

I have to accept different types of xml formats in the node api, based on the value that is defined need to perform respective operations.

Here is the code which I'm trying:

```
var xmlparser = require('express-xml-bodyparser');
    app.post('/xmlparser',xmlparser({trim: false, explicitArray: false}),function(request,reply){
    var data = JSON.stringify(request.body);
    var arr_data =JSON.parse(data);
    //code to access and display values from the xml

    console.log("xml 1:"+arr_data['ps0:tfg']['ps0:header']['ps1:messageid']);
    console.log("xml 2:"+arr_data['ps1:hls']['ps1:header']['ps1:messageid']);
})
Here are the 2 different xml, that takes as an input.

xml 1:
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ps0:TFG xmlns:ns0="http://www.google.com/LOGO/Common">
    <ps0:Header version="1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://www.google.com/LOGO/Common">
    <ps1:MessageId>MESSAGE001</ns1:MessageId>
    </ps0:Header>
    </ns0:TFG>

xml 2:    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ps0:HLS xmlns:ns0="http://www.google.com/LOGO/Common">
    <ps0:Header version="1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://www.google.com/LOGO/Common">
    <ps1:MessageId>MESSAGE001</ns1:MessageId>
    </ps0:Header>
    </ps0:HLS>
```

I'm accepting different formats with in the same code as mentioned above, if i pass xml 1, xml 1 printing fine. if i pass the xml 2 as input, execution stops at 1st console log as the index is not available.

To resolve this I need to keep some conditions, atleast if it is showing undefined then i can mark in the condition, problem code is not executing if index mismatches.

Update: I have tried implementing try catch as well, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add some simple `if` conditions to restrict access to invalid array indexes:

```
app.post('/xmlparser',xmlparser({trim: false, explicitArray: false}), function(request,reply) {
  var data = JSON.stringify(request.body);
  var arr_data = JSON.parse(data);

  //code to access and display values from the xml

  if (arr_data['ps0:tfg'] &&
      arr_data['ps0:tfg']['ps0:header']) {
    console.log("xml 1:" + arr_data['ps0:tfg']['ps0:header']['ps1:messageid']);
  }

  if (arr_data['ps1:hls'] &&
      arr_data['ps1:hls']['ps1:header']) {
    console.log("xml 2:" + arr_data['ps1:hls']['ps1:header']['ps1:messageid']);
  }
})
```

Also, I notice that your xml seem to be malformed, you are mixing `ps0, ps1, ns0, ns1` in an incorrect way.